# How do I get this code to repeat without refreshing page? setInterval? Other?

Tags: javascript, flash, rotation, setinterval

Hello I've written a bit of Javascript that I need to get to run every second. It is actually a Flash design of the sun that is supposed to change with the actual position of the sun outside.

```
    this.addEventListener("tick",fl_RotateContinuously.bind(this));
    var currentdate = new Date();
    function fl_RotateContinuously(){
    this.sky1.rotation=(currentdate.getHours()*15-90)+(currentdate.getMinutes()*3/12)+(currentdate.getSeconds()*3/720);

  }
```

The above code works and displays the sun in the correct position. However, I need the code to run every second, otherwise the user needs to refresh the HTML page to see the new position of the sun. I've tried using the setInterval() code to get the function to run every second, however I must not be writing it correctly because it will not work. Perhaps this isn't even the correct way to do it at all... Can anyone show me the correct way to repeat this function every second?

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind showing your setInterval approach?

One way of implementing it would be:

```
window.setInterval(function() { fl_RotateContinuously(); }, 1000); //1000 (ms) = 1s
```

Comment: So I ended up putting:                **setInterval(fl_RotateContinuously.bind(this),1000);** which actually worked but then as I played it in a browser it just got slower and slower and slower.

Comment: I also tried your approach but it didn't work, I needed to manually refreshed the page to see any difference in the degree of rotation.

Comment: Well your code in your original post only shows that one variable is updated in the fl_RotateContinuously(); function. Perhaps your sun is only drawn once and not updated everytime you update the variable?

Comment: I might be using this function completely wrong. `this.addEventListener("tick",fl_RotateContinuously.bind(this));
    var currentdate = new Date();
    function fl_RotateContinuously(){
    this.sky1.rotation=(currentdate.getHours()*15-90)+(currentdate.getMinutes()*3/12)+(currentdate.getSeconds()*3/720);

  } ` I noticed that I can get objects to rotate continuously if the last line of code reads: `this.sky1.rotate+=10` But this is not the correct rotation for the sun... I need that equation after the = sign.

Comment: Its odd because this code works perfectly in ActionScript. `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, timehandler);
function timehandler(event:Event):void {
var currentdate:Date=new Date();
sky1.rotation=(currentdate.hours*15-90)+(currentdate.minutes*3/12)+(currentdate.seconds*3/720);

 }` Is there a better way to convert this code into JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

The way you use the setInterval Function is

```
setInterval(functionName, 1000)
```

The first parameter is the function name without calling it, and the second parameter is the time in milliseconds that you want it to wait to call the function again.

https://jsfiddle.net/rhbritton/01t8yq2h/